# I want to change the pdf file name according to correction file number value

Tags: apex, trigger

I had created an apex trigger on case object I want that when I change status to correction requested than correction file number field to be increment by 1 and I want to send the pdf WHEN CORRECTION FILE NUMBER VALUE IS 1 THAN PDF name should be correction counter 1.pdf when correction file number value increases to 2 than pdf file name should be correction counter 2.pdf.

In email template i had used this code:

```html
<messaging:attachment renderas="pdf" filename="Correction Counter{!relatedTo.Correction_file_number__c}.pdf">
```

First time when I change the status to correction requested then successfully correction file number is incremented from 0 to 1 and but it is showing pdf file name is correction counter 0.6.pdf. I want that pdf file name should be correction counter 1.pdf

Apex trigger code:

```java
trigger Correction_Counter on Case (before update) {
    Case cs = Trigger.New[0];
    if (cs.Status == 'Correction Submitted') {
        if (Trigger.oldMap.get(cs.Id).Status != Trigger.newMap.get(cs.Id).Status) {
            if (cs.Correction_Counters__c == 0) {
                cs.Correction_Counters__c = 0.1;
            } else {
                cs.Correction_Counters__c += 0.5;
            }
        }
    } else if (cs.Status == 'Correction Requested') {

        if (Trigger.oldMap.get(cs.Id).Status != Trigger.newMap.get(cs.Id).Status) {
            if (cs.Correction_file_number__c == 0) {
                cs.Correction_file_number__c = 0.1;
            } else {
                cs.Correction_file_number__c += 0.5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I see where you're using `cs.Correction_Counters__c = 0.1` and `cs.Correction_Counters__c += 0.5`. If you want whole numbers, you'll want to remove the decimal points in these values and change them to integers.

From looking at the logic, it appears you may be trying to increment in points and half steps as well (ver 1.1, 1.2, vs 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, etc.), in which case you may need to change your if-else logic entirely.